# Use of xsl:when

Tags: xslt

I have made use of xsl:when to display my details. The details which I need to display is a title of the book. Now I want to display the title with one change. If the title is 'Cpp.....' I need to replace it with 'C++....' and display that book with this title in the browser.
This is to be incorporated for all books which have Cpp  in their title.

I have edited my quesition.
Can you help me with this?

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="rdf rss"
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"      

     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:rss="http://my.netscape.com/rdf/simple/0.9/"    

     xmlns:kb="http://protege.stanford.edu/kb#">

<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="wt:sparql/wt:results/wt:result"
    xmlns:wt="http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#">
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    <h3>
    <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="wt:binding[@name='count']/wt:literal &lt;= 5">
    <a style="color:red">
    <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
prepareEditValue('<xsl:value-of select="wt:binding[@name='x']/wt:uri"></xsl:value-of>', false);
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="wt:binding[@name='title']/wt:literal" />
    </a>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="wt:binding[@name='count']/wt:literal &lt;= 50">
    <a style="color:blue">
    <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
    prepareEditValue('<xsl:value-of select="wt:binding[@name='x']/wt:uri"></xsl:value-of>', false);
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="wt:binding[@name='title']/wt:literal" />
    </a>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
    <a>
    <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
    prepareEditValue('<xsl:value-of select="wt:binding[@name='x']/wt:uri"></xsl:value-of>', false);
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="wt:binding[@name='title']/wt:literal" />
    </a>
    </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    </h3>
    <div>
    <xsl:value-of select="wt:binding[@name='description']/wt:literal" />            Price:
    <xsl:value-of select="wt:binding[@name='price']/wt:literal" />
    <xsl:value-of select="wt:binding[@name='currency']/wt:literal" />
    <div style="float:right;">
    <input type="button" value="Edit">
    <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
    prepareEditValue('<xsl:value-of select="wt:binding[@name='x']/wt:uri"></xsl:value-of>', true);
    </xsl:attribute>
    </input>
    <input type="button" value="Delete">
    <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
    deleteBookDialog('<xsl:value-of select="wt:binding[@name='x']/wt:uri"></xsl:value-of>');
    </xsl:attribute>
    </input>
    </div>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The rdf file which has the data is

Welcome to C
    yy
    $
    8
    8

Cpp Primer Plus
    Stephen Prata
    â‚¬
    36.94
    88

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://protege.stanford.edu/kb#Linux Programming Bible">
<kb:Title>Linux Programming Bible</kb:Title>
<kb:Author>John Goerzen</kb:Author>
<kb:Currency>$</kb:Currency>
<kb:Price>77</kb:Price>
<kb:Count>34</kb:Count>
</rdf:Description>

<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://protege.stanford.edu/kb#CSharp-The Basics">
<kb:Title>CSharp-The Basics</kb:Title>
<kb:Author>Vijay Mukhi</kb:Author>
<kb:Currency>â‚¬</kb:Currency>
<kb:Price>56</kb:Price>
<kb:Count>6</kb:Count>
</rdf:Description>

<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://protege.stanford.edu/kb#Cpp Primer Answer Book">
<kb:Title>Cpp Primer Answer Book</kb:Title>
<kb:Author>Clovis L.Tondo</kb:Author>
<kb:Currency>$</kb:Currency>
<kb:Price>24.40</kb:Price>
<kb:Count>100</kb:Count>
</rdf:Description>

<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://protege.stanford.edu/kb#Ajax for Dummies">
<kb:Title>Ajax for Dummies</kb:Title>
<kb:Author>Steve Holzner</kb:Author>
<kb:Currency>$</kb:Currency>
<kb:Price>21.89</kb:Price>
<kb:Count>3</kb:Count>
</rdf:Description>

<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://protege.stanford.edu/kb#Beginning Programming with 
Cpp For Dummies">
<kb:Title>Beginning Programming with Cpp For Dummies</kb:Title>
<kb:Author>Stephen R.Davis</kb:Author>
<kb:Currency>$</kb:Currency>
<kb:Price>19.69</kb:Price>
<kb:Count>99</kb:Count>
</rdf:Description>

<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://protege.stanford.edu/kb#Programming in ANSI C">
<kb:Title>Programming in ANSI C</kb:Title>
<kb:Author>Stephen G.Kochan</kb:Author>
<kb:Currency>$</kb:Currency>
<kb:Price>99</kb:Price>
<kb:Count>9</kb:Count>
</rdf:Description>

<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://protege.stanford.edu/kb#Introduction to Programming 
 Using Java">
<kb:Title>Introduction to Programming Using Java</kb:Title>
<kb:Author>David J.Eck</kb:Author>
<kb:Currency>$</kb:Currency>
<kb:Price>89</kb:Price>
<kb:Count>23</kb:Count>
</rdf:Description>

<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://protege.stanford.edu/kb#Crafting a Compiler with C">
<kb:Title>Crafting a Compiler with C</kb:Title>
<kb:Author>Charles N.Fischer</kb:Author>
<kb:Currency>$</kb:Currency>
<kb:Price>95</kb:Price>
<kb:Count>8</kb:Count>
</rdf:Description>

<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://protege.stanford.edu/kb#Sams Teach Yourself C Sharp 
 in 24 Hours">
<kb:Title>Sams Teach Yourself C Sharp in 24 Hours</kb:Title>
<kb:Author>Sams</kb:Author>
<kb:Currency>$</kb:Currency>
<kb:Price>89</kb:Price>
<kb:Count>9</kb:Count>
</rdf:Description>

<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://protege.stanford.edu/kb#Compiler Constructions">
<kb:Title>Compiler Constructions</kb:Title>
<kb:Author>Jeremy Perk</kb:Author>
<kb:Currency>$</kb:Currency>
<kb:Price>88</kb:Price>
<kb:Count>9</kb:Count>
</rdf:Description>

<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://protege.stanford.edu/kb#Real Time Concepts for   
Embedded Systems">
<kb:Title>Real Time Concepts for Embedded Systems</kb:Title>
<kb:Author>Qing Li</kb:Author>
<kb:Currency>â‚¬</kb:Currency>
<kb:Price>109</kb:Price>
<kb:Count>88</kb:Count>
</rdf:Description>

<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://protege.stanford.edu/kb#Introduction to Algorithms">
<kb:Title>Introduction to Algorithms</kb:Title>
<kb:Author>Thomas Cormen</kb:Author>
<kb:Currency>$</kb:Currency>
<kb:Price>33</kb:Price>
<kb:Count>6</kb:Count>
 </rdf:Description>

 <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://protege.stanford.edu/kb#Begineer to Cpp  ">
<kb:Count>7</kb:Count>
<kb:Price>77</kb:Price>
<kb:Currency>$</kb:Currency>
<kb:Author>Harry</kb:Author>
<kb:Title>Begineer to Cpp  </kb:Title>
</rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Archana.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the code you have already?

Comment: This is another example of a bad question. Where is the XML document? You forgot it.

Comment: It looks like you want to replace a substring with another. There are many [answers](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+xslt+replace) here in SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this..

```
<xsl:if test="@title">
  <xsl:variable name="CPP">Cpp</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:when test="contains(@Title, $CPP)">
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(@title,'.cpp','')"/>
    <xsl:text>C++</xsl:text>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:othersise>
     <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
  </xsl:othersise>
</xsl:if>
```

It checks for a title attribute. If exists, compares it to value of variable `CPP`. If matches then prints our "C++".

Comment: @conqenator: I would expect a longer title... Don't you?

Comment: I had tried with the code you had given before but nothing changed.Now I have edited my question by giving my code.Please tell me how should I change my code to get the title with C++ if the title has Cpp in it.

Comment: @Archana:Can you please post your xml too.

Comment: I am sorry but which xml.I have only one web.xml which has servlet mappings.Or do you mean the rdf file which I am transforming into xslt then it is as given below

Comment: Replace @title with 'title' since its the element name and not attribute.

Comment: No I am at Stanford.I will check and see if the solution above which you have given will work or not.

Comment: Sorry But I am still getting title as 'Begineer to Cpp' instead of 'Begineer to C++'.

Comment: Sorry I am not at Stanford. Can you please help why I am not getting the desired output even after putting the changed code.

Comment: I am very sorry.But Can someone help me with this. When I place the code the line which is having 'replace' gives an error saying 'Xpath Invalid'

Comment: Try placing '@Title' in a variable, then apply `replace()` on that variable instead of on `@Title` directly. Are you using a web browser's parser? Or some other platform like Java/C# etc..?  Sorry, I cannot test my code right now and can only suggest what might work.